# Android. Parse.com: array is not updating

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

On every launch my app loads fresh data from parse.com and pins all objects to use app without network requests like this^

```
 public void pinKids() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstants.CLASS_KIDS);
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_PARENT, currentUser);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> kidsList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground(ParseConstants.LABEL_KIDS, new DeleteCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(ParseConstants.LABEL_KIDS, kidsList, new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {

                                Log.d("Hello", "pinKids");

                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}
```

One of the columns in my class is an array of strings (it stores history messages). I found that my code doesn't refresh this array if that array was updated from the other device (the same user did something on the other device). The rest of the data (other columns) refresh without problems. But the array of strings stays as it was downloaded at first launch.

In parse.com dashboard I see that array is updated. But code doesn't download this array while all the other columns are downloaded correctly.

Let me say that when I update this array on device-1 the new data is stored on device-1 and on "parse.com" too. But it doesn't update on device-2.

Please help!

Comment: But are you able to updated changes on Device1?

Comment: Yes. New item adds to the end of an array. Which applies to object pinned to local datastore on device-1 and to parse class eather.
But when I get this array from parse class due network on device-2 I cant see Items added from device-1.

And if I remove my app from any device and reinstall it. At the first launch it gets correct up-to-date data when I query objects at the first time. But then array doesn't update data from parse-cloud.

Comment: Have you printed it on console?

Comment: Yes. I tried adding item programmaticaly and typing it in console. Result is the same. 
I also found that array never refreshes and each device updates parse cloud with its own version of array. 
For example if you add item1 fom device-1. Array in parse-cloud contains item1. If then you update array on device-2 with item2 and item3, Parse-array will contain only item2 and item3. Item1 will be lost because it was never loaded to device-2.

And if then you'll use device-1 to add item4. Parse-cloud will contain only item1 and item4. 

But all other columns (not arrays) update correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I've solved it.

This problem is a bug of parse.com.

I've created [an issue on parse's github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/127#issuecomment-139618788).
So I found that my problem is a part of parse's bug.

So the answer is: replace all calls to `getJSONArray(key)` with `getList(key)`. You might also need `revert()/revert(key)`